# How to maintain specific length for each word using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have three words in each line separted by dot.

```
Word1.Word2.Word3
Example1.Example2.Example3
```

Here are the three words but each word must be of specific length. Word1 must be of 10 characters, Word2 must be of 10 characters, Word3 must be of 16 characters. If any word is less than specific lenght of characters, it must be filled with spaces. So, it must be look like this -

```
Word1     .Word2     .Word3          
Example1  .Example2  .Example3
```

How can i check the words and fill up with spaces if not met with specific length with regexp in Notepad++ ?

Comment: I do not think that regex will help you here with padding up to the requested length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by adding lots of extra spaces, then removing excess ones.

1. Replace regex `\.` with `__________.` (I'm writing `_` instead of spaces because stackoverflow doesn't display leading and trailing spaces, but you should use spaces.)
2. Replace regex `$` with `________________`
3. Replace regex `([^.]{10})[^.]*\.` with `$1.`
4. Replace regex `([^.]{16})[^.]*$` with `$1`

Comment: Instead of [^.] i have used ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})(.*)\. to replace with \1\.

Comment: @ChandraSekharK, surely you'd need a space or `\s` inside the character class. In your example, the first section would become `Word1__________.` after the first after step 1 (and 2) above. Then your regex wouldn't match `Word1__________.`, because `([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})` wouldn't match `Word1_____`.