# in notepad++ replace convert comma separated spaces with regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have comma separated tokens, 
I need to convert them to tokens in colons separated by spaces.
I wanted to use regular expression in notepad++ but had a problem.

My input is:

```
aaaaa, bbb ,cccc, hhhh, fff,t
```

I would like to get as result:

```
aaaaa     bbb       cccc     hhhh      fff       t
```

Each token gets exactly 10 characters

My problem is how to make the output exactly 10 characters?

Comment: I don't think RegEx can count and math the way you want...

Comment: You might better use a programming language with the a callback possibility (`re.sub()` in `Python` or `preg_replace_callback()` in `PHP`).

Comment: This could be done in 2 steps, first replace the commas with a large number of spaces. Second collect 10 characters plus all the trailing spaces and replace with just the 10 characters. I think it could be done in 1 step if the file contained a space at the end, but adding that space could be considered an additional step, so I guess 2 steps is the minimum

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the one Toto pointed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain specific length for each word using regex in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535979/how-to-maintain-specific-length-for-each-word-using-regex-in-notepad)

Answer (score 8):

## Description

I see this as a two step process. Step One replace all the commas with 10 spaces. Step Two capture 10 characters and all trailing spaces, and replace with just the 10 captured characters.

---

## Step One - Replace commas with 10 spaces

```
,\s*|\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Replace with:** `__________` these are unbars, but you should really use ten or more spaces.

**Live Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/mR1eS9/1

**Sample Text**

```
aaaaa, bbb ,cccc, hhhh, fff,t
```

**After Replacement**

```
aaaaa          bbb           cccc          hhhh          fff          t                    
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789
```

<sub>Note: I inserted the number line here to help illustrate the number and position of characters</sub>

---

## Step Two - Capture 10 characters and all trailing spaces

```
(.{10})[^\S\n\r]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Replace with:** `$1`

**Live Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/uL8oO7/2

**Sample Text**

Because this is step two, the sample text is the output from step one above

```
aaaaa          bbb           cccc          hhhh          fff          t
```

**After Replacement**

```
aaaaa     bbb       cccc      hhhh      fff       t         
123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789
```

<sub>Note: I inserted the number line here to help illustrate the number and position of characters</sub>

Comment: Just search replace all commas with 10 spaces :-) in the first step.

Comment: Oh sure that would work too, but I wanted to ensure the spaces were added to the end of each line too. I guess the step one could be shortened to just `,|$`.

Answer (score 6):

Regex computation model is so simple that it cannot count. However, in situations when you have only nine possible non-empty matches you can run nine separate global replacements to cover all possibilities (underscores `_` are used in place of spaces  for clarity):

```
Search         Replacement
-------------  -----------
(?<=\b\S{9}),\s  _
(?<=\b\S{8}),\s  __
(?<=\b\S{7}),\s  ___
(?<=\b\S{6}),\s  ____
...
(?<=\b\S{1}),\s  _________
```

Each replacement operation matches a comma, space pair that follows `x` non-space characters, and replaces them with `10-x` spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a solution with a programming language might be better to read and comprehend.
Find code samples for `PHP` and `Python` below (can easily be adopted to other languages as well):

#### PHP

```
<?php
$string = "aaaaa, bbb ,cccc, hhhh, fff,t";
$regex = '~(\w+)(\s*,|$)~';
# look for word characters, followed by spaces (or not) 
# and a comma or the end of the string

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($match) {
        return str_pad($match[1], 10);
    },
    $string);
echo $string;
# aaaaa      bbb       cccc       hhhh       fff       t         
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/Ny9RrS).

---

#### Python

```
import re

string = "aaaaa, bbb ,cccc, hhhh, fff,t";

def repl(match):
    return match.group(1).ljust(10)

rx = r'(\w+)(\s*,|$)'
string = re.sub(rx, repl, string)
print string
```

A [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/kAwzx8) as well.